# Count of Salesforce batches used in the Org

Tags: apex, soql, batch

When I look at the "Monitor Bulk Data Load Jobs" link in my salesforce org, I see a count of batches consumed in the last 24 hours. An example is shown below.

```
Your organization has processed **821 batches** in the last 24 hours. Your organization can process 2,000 batches in a 24-hour period.
```

Is there a way to get this information by running a SOQL?

Comment: the object to query (if it were queryable -- not possible as of Winter 18) is `AsyncApiJob`

Answer (score 2):

From [this](https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/monitoring_async_api_jobs.htm) it doesn't seem like there's a way to query for Bulk Load jobs.

You can query the AsyncApexJob table for a count of records where the type is BatchApex, which is the only seemingly log of all things Batch

```
Select count(Id) from asyncapexjob where JobType='BatchApex' and CreatedDate > Yesterday
```

However this doesn't seem to include Bulk Data Loads

Answer (score 2):

The snippet of code below gets the number of batches, and also the number of items in all batches:

```
List<AsyncApexJob> lstjobs=[
    SELECT
        Id,
        TotalJobItems
    FROM
        AsyncApexJob
    WHERE
        CompletedDate = TODAY
        AND JobType='BatchApex'];

Integer jobItemsCount = 0;
Integer batchesCount = 0;
for(AsyncApexJob async : lstjobs) {
    jobItemsCount += async.TotalJobItems; //Add the no of batches processed
    batchesCount++;
}
```

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't seem to work because of two reasons. 1) This doesn't seem to include bulk data loads as techtrekker mentioned in the below note. 2) CompletedDate = TODAY is not the correct where clause. It has to be a running 24 hour window. So, I tried CompletedDate >= System.now().addseconds(-86400) in a apex job and still the result was wrong because of #1.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use HTTP requests to get that info. See [Bulk API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/index_Left.htm) for more info, [this link looks particularly interesting](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/asynch_api_batches_get_info.htm?CSHID=asynch_api_batches_get_info.htm).